# How to replace unwanted value in string with regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

A string containing below values:

```
Dim abc As String = 'UserId1'|'ValueA1'|'ValueB1'|'ValueC1', 'UserId2'|'ValueA2'|'ValueB2'|'ValueC2'
```

**Current Function**

```
Dim arrAll As String() = abc.Split(",")
Dim UserIdList As New List(Of String)
Dim ValueAList As New List(Of String)
Dim ValueBList As New List(Of String)
Dim ValueCList As New List(Of String)

For i = 0 To UBound(arrAll)
    Dim arrSeparate As String() = arrAll(i).Split("|")
    UserIdList.Add(arrSeparate(0))
    ValueAList.Add(arrSeparate(1))
    ValueBList.Add(arrSeparate(2))
    ValueCList.Add(arrSeparate(3))
Next
```

I'm trying to separate the value above into 4 separate list without using Split / Loop functions.

With regular expression, I'm only able to retrieve all the 'UserId' or 'ValueC'. How can I retrieve 'ValueA' or 'ValueB'? 
I'm not familiar with regular expression. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Regular expression**

1. \|'([^']*)'
2. '([^']*)'\|

**Result**

1. 'UserId1', 'UserId2'
2. 'ValueC1', 'ValueC2'

Comment: Maybe all you need is to split the string with `|`?

Comment: I don't want to use split, because i want to have 4 list.
List 1 - Value1', 'Value1'
List 2 - Value2', 'Value2'
List 3 - Value3', 'Value3'
List 4 - Value4', 'Value4'

Comment: Your question really isn't clear.  You say you can only retrieve 'Value1' or 'Value4' - but you don't say what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have working code with loops, why the need for regex? Just a few adjustments to your code. The small c in the Char array tells the compiler that this is a Char not a String.

If you don't have Option Strict on - turn it on NOW!

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim abc As String = "'UserId1'|'ValueA1'|'ValueB1'|'ValueC1', 'UserId2'|'ValueA2'|'ValueB2'|'ValueC2'"
    Dim arrAll As String() = abc.Split(","c)
    Dim UserIdList As New List(Of String)
    Dim ValueAList As New List(Of String)
    Dim ValueBList As New List(Of String)
    Dim ValueCList As New List(Of String)
    'To get rid of single quote and spaces
    Dim charsToTrim() As Char = {"'"c, " "c}
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrAll)
        Dim arrSeparate As String() = arrAll(i).Split("|"c)
        UserIdList.Add(arrSeparate(0).Trim(charsToTrim))
        ValueAList.Add(arrSeparate(1).Trim(charsToTrim))
        ValueBList.Add(arrSeparate(2).Trim(charsToTrim))
        ValueCList.Add(arrSeparate(3).Trim(charsToTrim))
    Next
    'Inspect the values in your lists
    Debug.Print("ID List")
    For Each s In UserIdList
        Debug.Print(s)
    Next
    Debug.Print("A List")
    For Each s In ValueAList
        Debug.Print(s)
    Next
    Debug.Print("B List")
    For Each s In ValueBList
        Debug.Print(s)
    Next
    Debug.Print("C List")
    For Each s In ValueCList
        Debug.Print(s)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

this should return all char sequences not containg | or '

```
[^'\|]*
```